# Reconstruct near plane ray intersection with camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, hlsl

I am trying to reconstruct the point where the ray of the camera rendering the current pixel intersects the near plane.

I need the coordinates of the intersection point in the local coordinates of the object being rendered.

This is my current implementation:

`float4 nearClipLS = mul(inv_modelViewProjectionMatrix , float4((i.vertex.x / i.vertex.w), (i.vertex.y / i.vertex.w),-1., 1.)); nearClipLS /= nearClipLS.w;`

[image: Drawing of problem]

Answer (score 1):

There's got to be a more efficient way to do it, but the following should, in theory, work.

Find the offset vector from the camera to the pixel:

```
float3 cam2pos = v.worldPos - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
```

Get the camera's forward vector:

```
float3 camFwd = UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV[2].xyz;
```

Get the dot product of the two to determine how far the point projects in the direction of the camera's forward axis:

```
float projDist = dot(cam2pos, camFwd);
```

Then, you should be able to use that data to re-project the point onto the near clip plane:

```
float nearClipZ = _ProjectionParams.y;
float3 nearPos = _WorldSpaceCameraPos+ (cam2pos * (nearClipZ  / projDist));
```

This solution doesn't address edge cases (like when it's even with or behind the camera, which could cause problems), so you may want to check those once you get it working.

Comment: This would return world coordiantes right ? So i would transform it with :
`mul(unity_WorldToObject, nearPos);`?

Comment: Yes, it returns world coordinates.  If you need the coordinates to be in object space, then yes, that would be the correct course of action.

Comment: it seems to be kind of right, but with a mirrored axis. 

When I output the world nearPos to a plane, I have black in the upper right corner, green at the bottom and red on the left:

https://imgur.com/a/vX3h5op

Comment: Isn't this basically the [Intercept Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)?